# Como enviar dados de um clientdataset via post no delphi

Tags: delphi

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que eu preciso enviar os dados de um ClientDataSet (Delphi) para um sistema web via Post.
Como eu devo proceder?
Grato.

Comment: Como foi montada essa comunicação ?
Você já tem um Serviço para isso ?
O fato que você estar querendo enviar por post, acredito que sejam informações  de autenticação, certo ?
Se sim, ela deverá ser enviada no cabeçalho da requisição.

Comment: Eu vou enviar para um sistema web que eu tenho acesso. Seria isso?

Comment: Eu quero enviar dados de uma tabela que estão num clientDataSet. Deve ser via post para ficar protegido. O sistema é desktop.

Comment: Pois é, mas acredito que você deveria ter um servidorzinho REST para fazer esse tipo de requisição. Talvez um DataSnap se seu projeto for pequeno, mas eu recomento tentar usar a mORMot. Esse cara se comunicaria com seu WebService.

Comment: Cara, agora acho que entendi a sua pergunta.
Você pode usar os componentes da Indy para fazer algumas requisições.
Eu não lembro muito bem como eles funcionam, vou tentar montar um protótipo e dar uma pesquisada. Mas basicamente, ele consegue requisitar uma endereço, e você passa as informações no parametro da URL.

Comment: Isso. Vou tentar o indy. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyIdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  oStringList: TStringList;
  sResponse: String;
begin
  oStringList := TStringList.Create;
  oStringList.Add('usuario=victor');
  oStringList.Add('senha=12345');

  MyIdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    sResponse := MyIdHTTP.Post('http://SeuEndereco...', oStringList);
  finally
    MyIdHTTP.Free;
    oStringList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

PS: Se for https, basta criar um `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` e atribuir para a propiedade `IOHandler` do `MyIdHTTP`, e também disponibilizar as dlls `libeay32` e `ssleay32`, junto com o executável.

Comment: O oStringList é uma lista para conexão, certo?
Não será necessário utilizar login e senha para recebimento.
O sistema em PHP vai usar Rest para receber as informações.
Grato.

Comment: O recebimento vai ser mais ou menos assim: http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/

Comment: Não, a lista serve para você passar os parâmetros de entrada. 
Se eu for fazer uma consulta no google.com, eu alimento o parâmetro "q" com a string que eu quero buscar, ex: www.google.com.br/?q=StackOverflow

Neste caso, você alimentaria a lista com "q=" + "StackOverflow"

Comment: Entendi e acho que sua resposta está certa.
Vou fazer mais um teste e já te dou a ponto.

Comment: E ai @fabricio_wm, deu certo ?

Comment: Desculpa. 
Achei que eu já tivesse te dado o Feedback.
Funcionou.
Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Opa, muito bom então. Valeu